# how to integrate template inside email

Tags: php, email

i want to integrate template inside my email but the problem is that the path of the template that i am giving once arrived at my email box is displayed as a text.
so my script is :

```
$mail->From = 'user@gator4339.hostgator.com';
                            $mail->FromName = 'fekri';
                            $mail->addAddress('asa@gmail.com', 'fdgf');     // Add a recipient
                            $mail->addAddress('sa@gmail.com');               // Name is optional
                            $mail->addReplyTo('sa@gmail.com', 'ss');
                            $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
                            $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');


                    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

                        $message = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) .'/../views/emailFoldre/sendemails.php';



                        $headers = 'from fekrin';
                    $mail->Body = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) .'/../views/emailFoldre/sendemails.php';
                        // $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
                        //mail('maqajma@gmail.com',  $headers , $message);
                        if(!$mail->send()){

    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

and as result i get home/publi_html..../../views/emailFoldre/sendemails.php
this is sendemails.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <head>
<!-- If you delete this tag, the sky will fall on your head -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>ZURBemails</title>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; width: 100% !important; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">&#13;
&#13;
<!-- HEADER -->&#13;
<table class="head-wrap" bgcolor="#999999" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><tr style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><td style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;"></td>&#13;
        <td class="header container" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; display: block !important; max-width: 600px !important; clear: both !important; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">&#13;
            &#13;
                <div class="content" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; max-width: 600px; display: block; margin: 0 auto; padding: 15px;">&#13;
                    <table bgcolor="#999999" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><tr style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><td style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x50/" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; max-width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;" /></td>&#13;
                        <td align="right" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><h6 class="collapse" style="font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; line-height: 1.1; color: #444; font-weight: 900; font-size: 14px; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0; padding: 0;">Hero</h6></td>&#13;
                    </tr></table></div>&#13;
                &#13;
        </td>&#13;
        <td style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;"></td>&#13;
    </tr></table><!-- /HEADER --><!-- BODY --><table class="body-wrap" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><tr style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><td style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;"></td>&#13;
        <td class="container" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; display: block !important; max-width: 600px !important; clear: both !important; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">&#13;
&#13;
            <div class="content" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; max-width: 600px; display: block; margin: 0 auto; padding: 15px;">&#13;
            <table style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><tr style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><td style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;">&#13;
                        &#13;
                        <h3 style="font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; line-height: 1.1; color: #000; font-weight: 500; font-size: 27px; margin: 0 0 15px; padding: 0;">Welcome, Elijah Baily</h3>&#13;
                        <p class="lead" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 17px; line-height: 1.6; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 0;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.</p>&#13;
                        &#13;
                        <!-- A Real Hero (and a real human being) -->&#13;
                        <p style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.6; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 0;"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; max-width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;" /></p><!-- /hero -->&#13;
                        &#13;
                        <!-- Callout Panel -->&#13;
                        <p class="callout" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.6; background-color: #ECF8FF; margin: 0 0 15px; padding: 15px;">&#13;
                            votre message a été envoyé à l'Annonceur avec avec Succès, Merci. <a href="#" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #2BA6CB; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; padding: 0;">Do it Now! »</a>&#13;
                        </p><!-- /Callout Panel -->&#13;
                        &#13;
                        <h3 style="font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; line-height: 1.1; color: #000; font-weight: 500; font-size: 27px; margin: 0 0 15px; padding: 0;">Title Ipsum <small style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 60%; color: #6f6f6f; line-height: 0; text-transform: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;">This is a note.</small></h3>&#13;
                        <p style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.6; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 0;">votre message a été envoyé à l'Annonceur avec avec Succès, Merci.</p>&#13;
                        <a class="btn" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #FFF; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; display: block !important; background-image: none !important; background-color: #666; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 10px 16px;">Click Me!</a>&#13;
                                                &#13;
                        <br style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;" /><br style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;" /><!-- social & contact --><table class="social" width="100%" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; width: 100%; background-color: #ebebeb; margin: 0; padding: 0;" bgcolor="#ebebeb"><tr style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><td style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;">&#13;
                                    &#13;
                                    <!--- column 1 -->&#13;
                                    <table align="left" class="column" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; width: 280px; float: left; min-width: 279px; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><tr style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><td style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 15px;">              &#13;
                                                &#13;
                                                <h5 class="" style="font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; line-height: 1.1; color: #000; font-weight: 900; font-size: 17px; margin: 0 0 15px; padding: 0;">Connect with Us:</h5>&#13;
                                                <p class="" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.6; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 0;"><a href="#" class="soc-btn fb" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #FFF; font-size: 12px; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; display: block; text-align: center; background-color: #3B5998 !important; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 3px 7px;">Facebook</a> <a href="#" class="soc-btn tw" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #FFF; font-size: 12px; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; display: block; text-align: center; background-color: #1daced !important; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 3px 7px;">Twitter</a> <a href="#" class="soc-btn gp" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #FFF; font-size: 12px; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; display: block; text-align: center; background-color: #DB4A39 !important; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 3px 7px;">Google+</a></p>&#13;
                        &#13;
                                                &#13;
                                            </td>&#13;
                                        </tr></table><!-- /column 1 --><!--- column 2 --><table align="left" class="column" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; width: 280px; float: left; min-width: 279px; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><tr style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><td style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 15px;">             &#13;
                                                                            &#13;
                                                <h5 class="" style="font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; line-height: 1.1; color: #000; font-weight: 900; font-size: 17px; margin: 0 0 15px; padding: 0;">Contact Info:</h5>                                                &#13;
                                                <p style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.6; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 0;">Phone: <strong style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;">408.341.0600</strong><br style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;" />&#13;
                Email: <strong style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><a href="emailto:hseldon@trantor.com" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #2BA6CB; margin: 0; padding: 0;">hseldon@trantor.com</a></strong></p>&#13;
                &#13;
                                            </td>&#13;
                                        </tr></table><!-- /column 2 --><span class="clear" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; display: block; clear: both; margin: 0; padding: 0;"></span>    &#13;
                                    &#13;
                                </td>&#13;
                            </tr></table><!-- /social & contact --></td>&#13;
                </tr></table></div>&#13;
                                    &#13;
        </td>&#13;
        <td style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;"></td>&#13;
    </tr></table><!-- /BODY --><!-- FOOTER --><table class="footer-wrap" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; width: 100%; clear: both !important; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><tr style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><td style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;"></td>&#13;
        <td class="container" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; display: block !important; max-width: 600px !important; clear: both !important; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">&#13;
            &#13;
                <!-- content -->&#13;
                <div class="content" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; max-width: 600px; display: block; margin: 0 auto; padding: 15px;">&#13;
                <table style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><tr style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><td align="center" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;">&#13;
                        <p style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.6; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 0;">&#13;
                            <a href="#" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #2BA6CB; margin: 0; padding: 0;">Terms</a> |&#13;
                            <a href="#" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #2BA6CB; margin: 0; padding: 0;">Privacy</a> |&#13;
                            <a href="#" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #2BA6CB; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><unsubscribe style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;">Unsubscribe</unsubscribe></a>&#13;
                        </p>&#13;
                    </td>&#13;
                </tr></table></div><!-- /content -->&#13;
                &#13;
        </td>&#13;
        <td style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;"></td>&#13;
    </tr></table><!-- /FOOTER --></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$mail->Body` in this code is set to the file's **name**, and not the file's **content**. To fix it, and assuming the file name is correct, the following line:

```
$mail->Body = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) .'/../views/emailFoldre/sendemails.php';
```

Should be simply changed to:

```
$mail->Body = file_get_contents(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) .'/../views/emailFoldre/sendemails.php');
```

*Notes*:

1. `$message` isn't used anywhere - it's better to remove it to avoid confusion
2. Indentation really needs to be fixed